# How to prevent React hooks from erasing previous data while loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, flicker

I'm trying react hooks and made my first component. Everything is working fine except a flickering problem wile data is loading, here's my component (a simple list of articles, with prev/next pagination) :

```js
function InfoFeed ({ limit, uuid }) {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(1)
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(gql(queries.InfoFeed), {
    variables: {
      offset: (articlesByPage * (currentIndex - 1))
    }
  })
  const { articles } = data

  const incrementCb = () => setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === maxPaginationIndex ? 1 : currentIndex + 1)
  const decrementCb = () => setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 1 ? maxPaginationIndex : currentIndex - 1)

  return (
    <Panel title="Fil Info">
      <StyledList>
        {articles && articles.map((article, index) => (<InfoItem key={index} article={article}/>))}
      </StyledList>
      <button onClick={incrementCb}>next</button>
      <button onClick={decrementCb}>prev</button>
    </Panel>
  )
}
```

The problem is : when clicking on prev/next buttons, it launches a server request, `loading` is automatically set to `true`, and `data` is set to `undefined`. Data being undefined, the article list is empty while loading. I could show a spinner conditionnaly using the `loading` variable, but it's a pretty fast request (no spinner required), and it wouldn't prevent the previous data from disappearing, which is the cause of this unwanted flickering.

Any idea how to deal with this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by migrating to official @apollo/react-hooks bindings, since I was using https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I have not used React hooks much, or Apollo at all. This answer is speculative.

From looking at [the documentation for `@apollo/react-hooks`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#usequery), I would try setting the `fetchPolicy` for your query to `network-only`. That way, it shouldn't return the initial data from the cache (which is empty) first.

```
const { data, loading } = useQuery(gql(queries.InfoFeed), {
  variables: {
    offset: (articlesByPage * (currentIndex - 1))
  },
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
});
```

Comment: I may have expressed myself poorly : the flickering doesn't happen on first render, but everytime I click on `next/prev` buttons. The cache actually helps, when I do `next`, then `prev`, the content is in the cache, the request is not launched, and no flickering happens.